# Buttons are not working using tabulator in VueJs

Tags: vue.js, button, tabulator

Here, I have setup a table using tabulator in my VueJs project. I have followed the instructions for tabulator setup in VueJs from: http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/frameworks#vue .I have added button like adding row and updating row but for some reason it is not working. I can see my button but it is not functioning.

Here is my code:

```
 <template>
<div class="table-wrapper">
    <div ref="table">
    </div>
    <v-btn color="green" @click="addRow">Add Row</v-btn>

</div>


</template>

 <script>
    var Tabulator = require('tabulator-tables')
    export default {
      name: 'Location',
      data: function () {
        return {
          tabulator: null, // variable to hold your table
          location: [] // data for table to display
        }
      },
      watch: {
        // update table if data changes
        location: {
          handler: function (newData) {
            this.tabulator.replaceData(newData)
          },
          deep: true
        }
      },
      created: function () {
        console.log('Location', this.$refs)
        this.initialize()
      },
       methods: {
       initialize () {
          axios.get('/api/location')
        .then(response => this.location =  response.data.location)

        },

         addRow() {
        // add your row here
        this.location.addRow({})
    }
       },
      mounted () {
        // instantiate Tabulator when element is mounted
        this.tabulator = new Tabulator(this.$refs.table, {
          data: this.location,
          layout:"fitDataStretch",   
          movableColumns:true,
          addRowPos:"bottom",
           // link data to table
          columns: [
            {title: 'Code', field: 'code', sorter: 'string',width: 100,  editor: 'input' , validator: "required"},
            {title: 'Name', field: 'name', sorter: 'string', width: 200 , validator: "required",editor:"autocomplete", editorParams:{allowEmpty:true, showListOnEmpty:true, values:true}},
            {title: 'Under', field: 'under', sorter: 'string', width: 200,  editor: 'input' , validator: "required"},
            {title: 'Status', field: 'status', sorter: 'string',width: 100,  editor: 'input' , validator: "required"},
            {title: 'Description', field: 'description', sorter: 'string', width: 200,  editor: 'input' , validator: "required"},
            {title: 'Depth', field: 'depth', sorter: 'string', width: 100,  editor: 'input' , validator: "required"}

          ]
        });




      },

    }
    </script>
<style scoped>

</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not a great idea to use jQuery and Vue.js in the same UI. Don't do it if you can avoid it.

Your buttons are not attached to any functions or actions in the Vue way.

Just use an event bind on the buttons, attaching it to one of your methods, to control what it does, like:

```
<v-btn color="green" @click="addRow">Add Row</v-btn>
```

and then on your component methods:

```
methods: {
    addRow() {
        // add your row here
        this.location.addRow({})
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate more because its still not working.

Comment: If is still not working, please provide the error and more details. It should be something regarding this Tabulator class.

Comment: @VictoSouto you can see in my question that I have edited the code as you have suggested but still buttons are not functioning and the problem is that when I compile my code no error is coming.

Comment: You have added the @click="addRow", but there is no addRow method on yout methods. And still no details about the error was provided.

Comment: @VictoSouto No error is showing but button is still not working.